# ¿Cómo convertir campos NULL a cero dentro de una función en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, null

Estoy utilizando una función que me convierte valores de string a valor tipo float. Me funciona correctamente, muestro mi función:

```
create function f_tipoFloat
(
@dato varchar(10)
)
returns float
as
begin
return(SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, @dato));
end
```

Debido a esta función puedo hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna MONTOCREDITO es de tipo string, esta programada que al recibir registros ahí me los convierta a float dentro de otra columna llamada MONTOCREDITOFLOAT, como pueden ver hay muchas celdas sin valor.

No puedo actualizar directamente de null a cero a la columna MONTOCREDITOFLOAT porque es proveniente de una función, imagino que la conversión debería hacerla dentro de la función o, ¿hay otra manera?

Quiere evitar que no me muestre los NULL de la siguiente imagen, necesito que aparezcan valores 0. Pudiendo así calcularme el TOTAL y no mostrarmelo en NULL tampoco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: "imagino que la conversión debería hacerla dentro de la función" ehh si.. lo intentaste ya ??

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer esto? Crear una función así solo va a lograr que todo se ejecute más lento. Puedo proporcionar ejemplos de esto si quieres.

Comment: Lo tengo de esa manera porque los registros a la BBDD provienen de una hoja de Excel, y que son cargados desde la web en un MVC .NET. Todos las columnas de mi tabla las tengo en tipo string, y el Excel solo me carga de esa forma. Por eso hago la función.

Comment: Y claro, estoy dispuesto a ver tus ejemplos. Por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta con un ISNULL

ya con eso puedes convertirlo al valor que quieras, en este ejemplo lo pasa a cero.

```
create function f_tipoFloat
(
@dato varchar(10)
)
returns float
as
begin
return(SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(FLOAT, @dato),0));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar la función `ISNULL` de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_tipoFloat (@dato varchar(10))
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @result float
  SET @result = (SELECT
    ISNULL(CONVERT(float, @dato), 0))
  RETURN @result
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Para eso SQLServer tiene [la función COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).
Le pasas varios parámetros (2..N) y se quedará con el primero que no sea igual a `NULL`.

En tu caso bastaría con crear la función de esta manera:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [DBO].[F_TIPOFLOAT]
(
@DATO VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN(SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(FLOAT, @DATO), 0) );
END
```

De esta forma, si el campo es `NULL`, devolverá un `0`.